# Debug in vim using pyclewn

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find out if is possible using vim as IDE to write python/c programms. Today I've installed pyclewn as a debugger. When I open it with `:Pyclewn pdb tests.py` all pyclewn windows are opened inside nerdtree window, is it possible to fix this issue and place them in main window.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got it, what I need 

`let g:pyclewn_args = "--window=bottom"`

Next question, how to restart python script again?
Maybe some one can suggest tutorial for pyclewn?